# Run gevent processes and server concurrently

Tags: python, bottle, gevent

How to run a given module given I want to run some functions concurrently that are not necessarily using routing (could be daemon services) while at the same time running the app server?

For example:

```
#some other route functions app.post(...)

#some other concurrent functions

def alarm():
    '''
    Run this service every X duration
    '''
    ALARM = 21 
    try:
        while 1:
            #checking time and doing something. Then finding INTERVAL
            gevent.sleep(INTERVAL)
    except KeyboardInterrupt,e:
        print 'exiting'
```

Do I have to use the above like this after **main** ?

```
gevent.joinall(gevent.spawn(alarm))

app.run(....)
```

or

```
gevent.joinall((gevent.spawn(alarm),gevent.spawn(app.run)))
```

The objective is run these alarm like daemon services, do their work and snooze while rest of service operations work as usual.
The server should start concurrently as well. correct me if im not on the right track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gevent comes with it's own WSGI servers, so it is really not necessary to use `app.run`. The servers are:

- [gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pywsgi.html#gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer)
- [gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.wsgi.html#gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer)

Both provide the same interface.

You can use these to achieve what you want:

```
import gevent
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

import requests

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer


# app = YourBottleApp

def alarm():
    '''
    Run this service every X duration
    '''
    ALARM = 21 
    while 1:
        #checking time and doing something. Then finding INTERVAL
        gevent.sleep(INTERVAL)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = WSGIServer(('', 8080), app)
    srv_greenlet = gevent.spawn(http_server.serve_forever)
    alarm_greenlet = gevent.spawn(alarm)

    try:
        gevent.joinall([srv_greenlet, alarm_greenlet])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        http_server.stop()
        print 'Quitting'
```

Comment: i'd like to ask whats the diff/ b/w pywsgi and wsgi?
in practical operation, how does starting either differ from app.run(localhost,server='gevent'..) ??

Comment: could i not just do http_serve = gevent.spawn(app.run, (addr,post),arg1,arg2); gevent.joinall([http_serve,alarm_greenlet]) ??

Comment: I believe that in the previous versions, pywsgi supported SSL, while wsgi did not. You could do that with `app.run`. Not sure how it'll help though.

Comment: I did do that and I chose server=gevent; although the alarm() printed out twice that its going to sleep, the server started fine though.

Yes I checked out the gevents docs. thanks for clarification. as of current release wsgi is an alias for pywsgi. pywsgi supports Streaming and pipelining while wsgi was based on libev and didnt support non-buffered request-response